# angular select ng-selected not working (with <option ng-repeat>)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I've spent an hour and tried every conceivable permutation of properties to bind a select to a model as object, and *ng-selected* does nothing.

```
<select ng-model="localModel.priceType">
    <option 
            ng-repeat="item in vm.priceTypes"
            ng-selected="localModel.priceType == item"
            ng-value="item"
            >{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

or

```
<select ng-model="localModel.priceType">
    <option 
            ng-repeat="item in vm.priceTypes"
            ng-selected="localModel.priceType.id == item.id"
            ng-value="item"
            >{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

or

```
<select ng-model="localModel.priceType">
    <option 
            ng-repeat="item in vm.priceTypes track by item.name"
            ng-selected="localModel.priceType.name == item.name"
            ng-value="item"
            >{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

The select list renders correctly, option values look funky i.e "object:875". and *selected* does not work.

I need ng-model to be the object, not object.someId.

**solved this by using ng-options instead of <option> ng-repat**

```
<select ng-model="localModel.priceType" ng-options="item as item.namefor item in vm.priceTypes track by item.name"></select>
```

Comment: Thats because you should be using `ng-options` with `ng-model` that contains a value from your array `vm.priceTypes[0]`
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: using ng-options directive instead of options with a repeat was the solution. still not sure why latter wouldn't work, but i won't lose sleep over it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ngValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) expects a string for the ngValue. To use ngRepeat with the `<option>` tag, then use `value="{{item}}"` instead of ng-value.  Expand the snippet below to see it working.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.vm = {
      priceTypes: [{
          id: 3,
          name: 'pound'
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: 'Yen'
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'dollar'
        }
      ]
    };
    //select model value
    $scope.localModel = {
      priceType: $scope.vm.priceTypes[1]
    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="localModel.priceType">
  <option 
            ng-repeat="item in vm.priceTypes as item"
            ng-selected="localModel.priceType.id == item.id"
            value="{{item}}"
            >{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
  <div>
    priceType: {{ localModel.priceType }}
  </div>
</div>
```

A simpler approach is to use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) on the `<select>` tag, with a combination of forms:

```
select as label for value in array track by expr
```

Refer to the *comprehension_expression* forms in the **Arguments** section under [Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#usage) for more information.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.vm = {
      priceTypes: [{
          id: 3,
          name: 'pound'
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: 'Yen'
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'dollar'
        }
      ]
    };
    //select model value
    $scope.localModel = {
      priceType: $scope.vm.priceTypes[1]
    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="localModel.priceType" ng-options="item as item.name for item in vm.priceTypes track by item.name">
</select>
  <div>
    priceType: {{ localModel.priceType }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for creating a snippet! do you know why it only seems to work with ng-options?

Comment: I have updated the explanation - apparently ngValue expects a string, so working with an object won't work so well...

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

> `ngSelected` does not interact with the `select` and `ngModel`
>   directives, it only sets the `selected` attribute on the element. If you
>   are using `ngModel` on the select, you should not use `ngSelected` on the
>   options, as `ngModel` will set the select value and selected options.

Try

```
<select ng-model="localModel.priceType">
  <option  ng-repeat="item in vm.priceTypes track by item.name"
           ng-value="item.name">
      {{item.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

You can change `ng-value` to any value you want from `vm.priceTypes[0]`.

Comment: thank you, but this does the same thing as my initial example. it makes the select work, but not the selected property